# How to save/restore the views in eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse, e4

I have two sections. In the left section I am using checkbox tableviewer for displaying list of file names. The right section is for showing graphs(I am using JFreechart). I have a handler which is used for dynamically adding tabs to the right side section. IF I am in first tab and made some checkbox selections in left side tableviewer ,the graph is displayed in right side. When I create a new tab(right side) , the left side tableviewer should reset.

When I select the first tab again and  I want to see the previous selection in left side section.Can anyone please give some ideas how to save/restore the views based on the tab change?

Left side section code for file viewer:

```
@PostConstruct
public void createComposite(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    tableViewer = new CheckboxTableViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    tableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

}

public void setTableInput(File[] selectedFiles) {
    tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new FileLabelProvider());
    prevSelectedFiles = selectedFiles;
    tableViewer.setInput(selectedFiles);
    tableViewer.addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {
            filesSelected = tableViewer.getCheckedElements();
// some code to display graph
}}}
```

Right side code(Graph)

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(final Composite parent) {
    final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset, title);
    new ChartComposite(parent, SWT.NONE, chart, true);

}

private JFreeChart createChart(TimeSeriesCollection dataset, String string) {
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            "REPORT GENERATION", "TimeStamp", "ms", dataset, true, true,
            false);
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);

    final XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setDataset(0, dataset);
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);
    Shape shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(-2.0, -2.0, 4.0, 4.0);

    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot
            .getRenderer();
    renderer.setSeriesShape(0, shape);
    renderer.setSeriesShape(1, shape);
    renderer.setSeriesShape(2, shape);
    renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
    renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, Color.GRAY);
    renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(1, Color.GRAY);
    renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(2, Color.GRAY);
    renderer.setUseFillPaint(true);
    renderer.setSeriesFillPaint(0, Color.red);
    renderer.setSeriesFillPaint(1, Color.green);
    renderer.setSeriesFillPaint(2, Color.blue);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.green);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, Color.blue);

    NumberAxis yaxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    yaxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
    yaxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
    plot.setRangeAxis(yaxis);
    DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setAutoTickUnitSelection(true);
    // axis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.SECOND,120));
    axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"));
    // DateAxis.createStandardDateTickUnits();
    axis.setTickMarksVisible(true);
    axis.setTickLabelsVisible(true);
    return chart;

}
public void setValue(ArrayList<TreeMap<Timestamp, Long>> statisticalValues, String protocolName, String statistics) {
    // //System.out
    // .println("setting the value for timeseries-->" + i);

    TimeSeries ts = null;
    for (TreeMap<Timestamp, Long> entries : statisticalValues) {

        ts = new TimeSeries(protocolName + "_" + statistics,
                Second.class);
        for (Entry<Timestamp, Long> seriesData : entries.entrySet()) {
            ts.addOrUpdate(new Second(seriesData.getKey()),
                    seriesData.getValue());
        }
    }
    dataset.addSeries(ts);

}
```

The handler responsible for dynamic creation of tab(Grapgh part):

```
public class DynamicPartsHandler {
@Execute
public void execute(EPartService partService, EModelService modelService,
        MApplication application,Shell shell) {
    String partName = "Graph";
    MPart part = partService
            .createPart("com.wincor.commtrace.project.partDescriptor.1");
    MPartStack stack = (MPartStack) modelService.find(
            "com.wincor.commtrace.project.partstack.2", application);
    stack.getChildren().add(part);

    part.setLabel(partName);
    part.setVisible(true);
    part.setCloseable(true);
    partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the code, what you have tried, that says more then 1000 words :)

Comment: Up to now i haven't done something with e4, but my first idea would be a Map (Key -> Tab; Value -> List of checkboxes), and if you select your first tab, you'll get the Checkboxes from your Map with the first tab as key.

Comment: In which part should I write the code? In handler or in the files part ? How to restore it?

Comment: I think yes, if this Handler class is responsible for Tab Generation, then before you create the new Tab, you save the one or all the other open Tabs in your Map, with all its Checkboxes and their current state. If you later re-select an older Tab you can iterate over the List of Checkboxes and restore them on your Tab. As a first quick idea. Maybe someone can give a better suggestion.

Comment: A map seems reasonable. `MPart` has a `getTransientData()` method that returns a map you can save transient data in.