# Persist the tableviewer elements of a part and restore it

Tags: java, eclipse, e4

I want to save and restore the checkbox tableviewer elements. To save the tableviewer I am using the following code

```
application.getPersistedState().put("Label",
            MyClassObject.tableViewer.toString());
```

I know its wrong to insert the value(MyClassObject.tableViewer.toString()) in key/value pair.I need to store all the values in the checkboxtableviewer and restore it.  Can anyone give me some ideas what should I insert in the persistedstate so that i can restore it back?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is much anyone can say about this. It depends entirely on your objects that you put in the tree and how you would go about recreating them.

Comment: Can you please look into the other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983170/how-to-save-restore-the-views-in-eclipse-e4?noredirect=1#comment36956281_23983170  I have a problem when switching the tabs how and when should I capture the values of the other part? It would be of great help.